# Using muenchian grouping to select distinct values in a subtree

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I know how to do muenchian grouping but that normally is applied to a whole document (?).

Here I want to find distinct values in subtrees.

e.g.

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2"/>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child id="2"/>
    <child id="3"/>
    <child id="3"/>
  </parent>
</root>
```

I want to map to

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2"/>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child id="2"/>
    <child id="3"/>
  </parent>
</root>
```

If I try

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="id_to_id" match="/root/parent/child" use="@id"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent">
          <parent>
            <xsl:for-each select="child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id_to_id',@id)[1])]">
              <child id="{@id}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>            
          </parent>       
        </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then it does the key over the whole document and I get

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child id="1" />
    <child id="2" />
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child id="3" />
  </parent>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually I've just created a solution but its a bit odd, ie generate an id for the parent node, and effectively we have a composite key of id attribute + id for the node

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="id_to_id" match="/root/parent/child" use="concat(@id,'|',generate-id(..))"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent">
          <parent>
            <xsl:for-each select="child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id_to_id',concat(@id,'|',generate-id(..)))[1])]">
              <child id="{@id}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>            
          </parent>       
        </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is this the standard way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. Except that you don't need the full path in a match pattern so that the key can be defined as `<xsl:key name="id_to_id" match="child" use="concat(@id,' |', generate-id(..))"/>`. And you could just copy the unique `child` nodes using  `<xsl:copy-of select="child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id_to_id',concat(@id,'|',generate-id(..)))[1])]"/>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k what do u think of the other copy/nodeset solution?

Comment: I think it's unnecessarily over-complicated.

Comment: ah ok...fair enough...I'm not massively happy with this weird generate-id() on the parent with this one, so I'm on the fence between the 2.

Comment: It's weird only in your eyes. Also, there is an alternative expression, if you prefer. In any case, unless I am missing something, you are using exactly the same method in both answers. The only difference is the redundant variable.

Comment: the other one uses a nodeset to scope the key, and doesnt require the generate id/composite key, so the key lookup is much simpler, but it requires an explicit nodeset

Comment: So you are exchanging a minor complexity for a major one. The solution in this answer is the standard approach. I have seen it and implemented it myself countless times and I wouldn't give it a second thought. Except maybe to consider using `[count(. | key(...)[1])=1]` to identify the 1irst node of the group instead of `generate-id()`.

Comment: I think the complexity issue is because u understand whats going on under the hood, from a code perspective, they both look comparable to me, and it maybe a stylistic issue at the code level. Its horribly easy to get these meunchian lookups wrong, especially with composite keys....I'll do it your way though, as you think its idiomatic. Thanks v much

Answer (score 0):

heres another equally bizarre solution, still not sure this is very sensible, is there some sort of XPath parenthesis or something I can use?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="id_to_id" match="child" use="@id"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent">
          <parent>
            <xsl:variable name="children">
              <xsl:copy-of select="child"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($children)/child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id_to_id',@id)[1])]">
              <child id="{@id}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>            
          </parent>       
        </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

now without meunchian grouping (which isnt what I want, but its a nice declarative approach), not suitable for anything but small groups of siblings.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent">
          <parent>
            <xsl:for-each select="child[not(@id = preceding-sibling::child/@id)]">
              <child id="{@id}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>            
          </parent>       
        </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should read the original article. The purpose of the Muenchian method is to avoid this inefficient pattern.

Comment: yep, I know why meunchian method exists and it order of (in)efficiency, but the above is an answer because its the natural way to do it without meunchian, I'm struggling with a natural way to do it with meunchian

Comment: Well, it's not a good answer. Certainly not today, over 20 years after Muenchian method has been published.

Comment: knuth anyone? "premature optimization is the root of all evil"....its there to give an example of a simple declarative expression, rather than answer the question. If n is small then I see no big issue.

Comment: That's not the case here. The Muenchian method carries no penalty, so there is no reason not to use it always.

Comment: I think the sibling expression is much shorter and simpler to understand. Put it like this, if it wasnt innefficient, noone would use the muenchian method.

Comment: Possibly - but the fact is that it *is* inefficient. And, as I said, the Muenchian method has no downside.  Once you get used to it, it won't bother you.